# Move Dynamics 365 Sales data to on-premise application via Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I've been digging and watching videos for days and am no closer to a solution. I'm trying to put together an integration where upon sales order creation in Dynamics 365 the record is sent to an on-premise ERP via Azure.

Specifically, I'm using Logic Apps and the CDS connector as a trigger to initiate the transfer but am lost as to how to proceed.

Onward from Logic Apps, do I connect to the on-premise machine via Azure Data Factory/Data Management Gateway? Or are those two separate things?

To communicate with the ERP, I need to use WCF. I've been told I'll need to use Azure Relay to do that. However, is there then a need for the Data Factory/Data Management Gateway components?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection) to connect to an on-premise system from Logic Apps.

This blog post walks through the process of connecting to an on-premise web service from a Logic App with a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/):

https://azureintegrations.com/2019/01/01/azure-connecting-to-an-onpremise-webservice-and-file-system-from-a-logic-app/

If instead of triggering an on-premise web service you could save data to the file system or to a DB then the process would be simpler as you could use standard connectors instead of creating custom ones.